# OpenVPN can' reach client Lan

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, openvpn, ping, route

I have a question about OpenVPN, I had made a "dev tun" connection between my office network and a VPC on Amazon.But....

in few words: Everething work, except: i c'ant ping the client Lan from the server lan.

As you can see on the diagram (link bellow) the Vpn server run on a Synology Nas in the office network.
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBIno.png)

The client succesfully connect to server and can access to all the Office network (using 192.168.1.XXX ip). (Yeah!).
But, from the office network i can't ping the Client lan (with 10.0.0.XXX) even from the server. Of course, i CAN ping the client with 10.8.0.6 from the server and from the lan.

To know:

- Source/Destination Checks is Disabled on ALL EC2 instance.
- Firewall disabled on VPNServer
- ALL Firewall disabled on VPNClient

I had spend sooo many time to find a solution.. and now adding and deleting route everywhere make me really creazy :/

Can someone help me to clarify the problem? Thank's in advance.

Server config:

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0" 
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
#route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0   
dev tun 

management 127.0.0.1 1195

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

dh /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/keys/dh1024.pem
ca /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/keys/server.key
max-clients 5
client-to-client
client-config-dir /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/ccd 
comp-lzo
persist-tun
persist-key
verb 3
#log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
keepalive 10 60
reneg-sec 0
plugin /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/lib/radiusplugin.so /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
duplicate-cn    
status /tmp/ovpn_status_2_result 30
status-version 2
proto udp6
port 1194
```

CCD File:

```
iroute 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

Client config:

```
dev tun
tls-client
remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 1194
pull
proto udp   
script-security 2 
ca ca.crt
comp-lzo
reneg-sec 0
auth-user-pass
```

OPENVPN SERVER ROUTE:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         bbox.lan        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Client Route:

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1       10.0.0.171     10
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.0.0.171    266
       10.0.0.171  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.0.171    266
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.0.171    266
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.5         10.8.0.6     20
         10.8.0.4  255.255.255.252         On-link          10.8.0.6    276
         10.8.0.6  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    276
         10.8.0.7  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  169.254.169.250  255.255.255.255         10.0.0.1       10.0.0.171     10
  169.254.169.251  255.255.255.255         10.0.0.1       10.0.0.171     10
  169.254.169.254  255.255.255.255         10.0.0.1       10.0.0.171     10
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.5         10.8.0.6     20
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.0.0.171    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.6    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.0.171    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    276
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a firewall somewhere that is dropping ICMP packets. This is a fairly common configuration that drops ping as well as the other ICMP protocols.

Comment: Thank's Catherine, i double check this right now. 
But what do you think about the fact that when i ping the "VPN client ip" (10.8.0.6) everything is correct? If there Is a Firewal, why he didn't drop all both ping?

Thank's you